# How do I upgrade to Ruby 2.2 on my Ubuntu system?

Tags: apt, upgrade, ruby, alternative

I’m using Ubuntu Linux.  Below is the uname info

```
myuser@myinstance:~$ uname -a
Linux myinstance 3.18.0-52-generic #123-Ubuntu SMP Fri Feb 19 14:27:58 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

I’m trying to upgrade the version of Ruby on my machine, which is currently installed at

```
/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1
```

I tried following the advice here — [Install ruby 2.2.3 via apt](https://askubuntu.com/questions/691134/install-ruby-2-2-3-via-apt), but unfortunately I get the error, “alternative path /usr/bin/ruby2.2 doesn't exist”.  What is the right way to upgrade my system to use Ruby 2.2 or greater?

```
myuser@myinstance:~/racertracks$ sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/ruby ruby /usr/bin/ruby2.2 400 \
>  --slave /usr/bin/rake rake /usr/bin/rake2.2 \
>  --slave /usr/bin/ri ri /usr/bin/ri2.2 \
>  --slave /usr/bin/rdoc rdoc /usr/bin/rdoc2.2 \
>  --slave /usr/bin/gem gem /usr/bin/gem2.2 \
>  --slave /usr/bin/irb irb /usr/bin/irb2.2 \
>  --slave /usr/share/man/man1/ruby.1.gz ruby.1.gz /usr/share/man/man1/ruby2.2.1.gz \
>  --slave /usr/share/man/man1/rake.1.gz rake.1.gz /usr/share/man/man1/rake2.2.1.gz \
>  --slave /usr/share/man/man1/ri.1.gz ri.1.gz /usr/share/man/man1/ri2.2.1.gz \
>  --slave /usr/share/man/man1/rdoc.1.gz rdoc.1.gz /usr/share/man/man1/rdoc2.2.1.gz \
>  --slave /usr/share/man/man1/gem.1.gz gem.1.gz /usr/share/man/man1/gem2.2.1.gz \
>  --slave /usr/share/man/man1/irb.1.gz irb.1.gz /usr/share/man/man1/irb2.2.1.gz
update-alternatives: error: alternative path /usr/bin/ruby2.2 doesn't exist
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Why not use [ruby 2.3](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=ruby2.3)  which is available in the repositories for 16.04 and 17.10 with

```
sudo apt update
```

After the update is finished run:

```
sudo apt-get install ruby2.3 ruby2.3-dev
```

Or try ruby 2.4 or 2.5

You can get those via the brightbox PPA

1. Add the repository and update

   ```
   sudo apt-add-repository ppa:brightbox/ruby-ng && sudo apt-get update
   ```
2. install

   ```
   sudo apt-get install ruby2.4
   ```

   or for **18.04**

   ```
   sudo apt-get install ruby2.5 ruby2.5-dev
   ```

Information on the status of packages in the aforementioned PPA can be found on the [“Brightbox” team launchpad page.](https://launchpad.net/%7Ebrightbox/+archive/ubuntu/ruby-ng/+index?batch=75&memo=75&start=75)

Alternatively you could try reverse hacking the error `alternative path /usr/bin/ruby2.2 doesn't exist` by creating it with `sudo mkdir /usr/bin/ruby2.2` and trying again.

Answer (score 0):

On Ubuntu 14.04 this worked for me to install `ruby 2.4.1`

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install git-core curl zlib1g-dev build-essential libssl-dev libreadline-dev libyaml-dev libsqlite3-dev sqlite3 libxml2-dev libxslt1-dev libcurl4-openssl-dev python-software-properties libffi-dev
```

Then install `rbenv`

```
    cd
    git clone git://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv.git .rbenv
    echo 'export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bash_profile
    echo 'eval "$(rbenv init -)"' >> ~/.bash_profile

    git clone git://github.com/sstephenson/ruby-build.git ~/.rbenv/plugins/ruby-build
    echo 'export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/plugins/ruby-build/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bash_profile
    source ~/.bash_profile
```

Now install ruby 2.4.1

```
rbenv install -v 2.2.3
```

To set 2.4.1 as a default use command `rbenv global 2.4.1`.